Ubuntu Web browser has blank devtools panel (running in WSL2)
I'm trying to use devtools panel in Ubuntu "Web" browser v 42.4 (former epiphany-browser) to inspect WebKit related issue, because it's the only WebKit based browser I can run on Windows machine from WSL2.
But when I open devtools panel, it's blank - 
I can hover on elements though, and tooltips are visible.
My guess was to open devtools in separate window, but it didn't work, result was the same.
How can I use devtools in that browser without installing additional virtual machines?
Windows 11 23H2, WSL2 - everything updated
